# PHP function not reaching the innermost nested if block

Tags: php, if-statement, nested, conditional-statements

So I've done a bit of testing with conditions, and for some reason I can't get this function to reach the innermost set of if/else.

I'm hoping someone can show me what I did?

```
function verifyStridersIdentity($post_name, $modpass) {
    //is the post name strider?
    //this part works
    if (strtolower($post_name) == 'strider') {
        //is the mod pass set?
        //this part ALSO works
        if (!empty($modpass)) {
            //modpass has some kind of value


            $staff_name = md5_decrypt($modpass, KU_RANDOMSEED);//is it actually Strider though?
            //this seems to be the block I am having trouble getting into?
            //I can not get a value of either of these next two return statements.
            if ($staff_name == $post_name) {
                return 'This Works, It\'s me!'; //this is Strider
            }
            else {
                return 'This is '.$staff_name.' attempting to be Strider. This has been logged.';
            }
        }
        else {
            return 'Anonymous Test';
        }
    }   
    else {
        return $post_name;
    }

}
```

I am hoping the inline comments explain well enough what's going on, but if not please ask me for more info.

Comment: Well, I thank anyone who reads this, but it turns out I actually called the function incorrectly. I will post the solution.

Comment: So it was working correctly. `$modpass` was empty, so it skipped that `if` block and went to the `else` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I called the function from the originating class, I used this code:

```
$post_name = verifyStridersIdentity($post_name,$modpass);
```

The problem there is that $modpass doesn't actually exist, so I am sending in a blank.

Therefore, the correcting call should have been something like this:

```
    $modpass = '';
    if (isset($_POST['modpassword'])) {
        $modpass = $_POST['modpassword'];
    }
    $post_name = verifyStridersIdentity($post_name,$modpass);
```

Comment: Wasn't the function returning `Anonymous test` because of this?

Comment: Correct, which is what made me look at what I was feeding the arguments in the calling class.